# Downloading files from URL

Tags: file, security, url, web

I have a question related to a security on website. Lets say that a visitor is currently on a http://www.example.com/. And visitor navigates to  gallery page. There he can find unique images that are displayed to him according to his log in details he provided earlier. A simple inspect on a picture shows him the URL to that picture: www.example.com/images/image_589326.png.

My question is: Is there a way for a user to somehow download all the files from
www.example.com/images/ folder, or somehow find the names of all images that are in that folder and simply view them with absolute URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. There are two main ways that this can be achieved: scraping & enumeration.

Through scraping someone would make a script that would look at the gallery page and make a list of all of the images, and then download them all.

Enumeration would just request http://www.example.com/images/image_000001.png through http://www.example.com/images/image_999999.png and download of the images that are present.

If the site is not proprely set up you may also be able to get a directory listing from http://www.example.com/images to see all of the files in the images/ directory.

Comment: Yes, but what if the names of the images weren't so predictable, or would just have more combinations to loop through? Like image_2314_93285717, would that be sufficient protection? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That would help prevent brute forcing file names, but the issue of just scraping off the gallery remains.